# NUnit/TeamCity Process exited with code -4

Tags: nunit, teamcity

I have a test project that runs locally without problem but it fails on our two build agents with the following message:

"Process exited with code -4 (Step: Run unit tests release MeasurementProgram(NUnit))"

What does "code -4" mean? Is it a TeamCity or NUnit error message? I have searched google for this particular error message but found nothing.

The build log for the failing build step looks like this:

````
[10:54:33][Step 8/10] Starting: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a6c5ca0ef741ad5d\MeasurementProgram\packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.9.0\tools\nunit3-console.exe C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\agentTmp\TUcUi6YjpZJlgpN1V44wTaX11CzkLXy5.nunit --result=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\agentTmp\TUcUi6YjpZJlgpN1V44wTaX11CzkLXy5.nunit.xml --noheader --where (cat==LongRunning||cat==AlgorithmLongRunning||cat==PerformanceLongRunning||cat==RegressionTestLongRunning||cat==IntegrationTestLongRunning||cat==DoseRegressionLongRunning)&&cat!=AlgorithmInvestigation&&cat!=TestTools --framework=net-4.0 --inprocess
[10:54:33][Step 8/10] in directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a6c5ca0ef741ad5d\MeasurementProgram\DeviceCtrl.Test\bin\Release
[10:54:33][Step 8/10] Runtime Environment
[10:54:33][Step 8/10]    OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.3.9600.0
[10:54:33][Step 8/10]   CLR Version: 4.0.30319.42000
[10:54:33][Step 8/10] 
[10:54:33][Step 8/10] Test Files
[10:54:33][Step 8/10]     C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\agentTmp\TUcUi6YjpZJlgpN1V44wTaX11CzkLXy5.nunit
[10:54:33][Step 8/10] 
[10:54:33][Step 8/10] Test Filters
[10:54:33][Step 8/10]     Where: (cat==LongRunning||cat==AlgorithmLongRunning||cat==PerformanceLongRunning||cat==RegressionTestLongRunning||cat==IntegrationTestLongRunning||cat==DoseRegressionLongRunning)&&cat!=AlgorithmInvestigation&&cat!=TestTools
[10:54:33][Step 8/10] 
[10:54:33][Step 8/10] 
[10:54:33][Step 8/10] Errors, Failures and Warnings
[10:54:33][Step 8/10] 
[10:54:33][Step 8/10] 1) Invalid : C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\agentTmp\TUcUi6YjpZJlgpN1V44wTaX11CzkLXy5.nunit
[10:54:33][Step 8/10] File type is not supported
[10:54:33][Step 8/10] 
[10:54:33][Step 8/10] Test Run Summary
[10:54:33][Step 8/10]   Overall result: Failed
[10:54:33][Step 8/10]   Test Count: 0, Passed: 0, Failed: 0, Warnings: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Skipped: 0
[10:54:33][Step 8/10]   Start time: 2019-09-16 08:54:33Z
[10:54:33][Step 8/10]     End time: 2019-09-16 08:54:33Z
[10:54:33][Step 8/10]     Duration: 0.026 seconds
[10:54:33][Step 8/10] 
[10:54:33][Step 8/10] Results (nunit3) saved as C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\agentTmp\TUcUi6YjpZJlgpN1V44wTaX11CzkLXy5.nunit.xml
[10:54:34][Step 8/10] Process exited with code -4
[10:54:34][Step 8/10] NUnit process finished with negative exit code -4 (unexpected failure). Reporting step failure.
[10:54:34][Step 8/10] Publishing artifacts
[10:54:34][Publishing artifacts] Collecting files to publish: [C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\agentTmp\TUcUi6YjpZJlgpN1V44wTaX11CzkLXy5.nunit => .teamcity\bt42_RUNNER_76]
[10:54:34][Publishing artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [ArtifactsCachePublisher]: C:/TeamCity/buildAgent/temp/agentTmp/TUcUi6YjpZJlgpN1V44wTaX11CzkLXy5.nunit => .teamcity/bt42_RUNNER_76
[10:54:34][Publishing artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [WebPublisher]: C:/TeamCity/buildAgent/temp/agentTmp/TUcUi6YjpZJlgpN1V44wTaX11CzkLXy5.nunit => .teamcity/bt42_RUNNER_76
[10:54:34][Step 8/10] ##teamcity[publishArtifacts 'C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\agentTmp\TUcUi6YjpZJlgpN1V44wTaX11CzkLXy5.nunit => .teamcity\bt42_RUNNER_76']
[10:54:34][Step 8/10] Process exited with code -4 (Step: Run unit tests release MeasurementProgram (NUnit))
[10:54:34][Step 8/10] Step Run unit tests release MeasurementProgram (NUnit) failed```
````

Answer (score 0):

It seems some of the extensions required by TeamCity aren't installed.

The easiest way is to install NUnit on TeamCity agents using [Agent Tools](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/installing-agent-tools.html) (it automatically installs all necessary extensions).

But if you want to do it manually, you need to install additional extensions to your project. Please, check the related [documentation page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/nunit.html#NUnit-InstallingExtensions) and [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-47211) in YouTrack.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by updating the NUnit.ConsoleRunner to version 3.10.0. As was suggested here https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/1525.